# Installing TFMpvalue for FunSeq2

Tags: software-installation

Based on the instructions I read, running `make` can solve the problem of TFMpvalue installation for FunSeq2 but when I do so I get this error:

```
root@milad:/home/milad/funseq2-1.0# cd '/home/milad/funseq2-1.0/TFM-Pvalue' 
root@milad:/home/milad/funseq2-1.0/TFM-Pvalue# make
g++ -O3 -DJASPAR=1 -DPROGRAM=0 TFMpvalue.cpp Matrix.cpp ArgumentException.cpp FileException.cpp ParseException.cpp  -o TFMpvalue-pv2sc
TFMpvalue.cpp: In function ‘void arguments(int, char* const*)’:
TFMpvalue.cpp:503:45: error: ‘getopt’ was not declared in this scope
   while (((option = getopt(argc,argv,options)) != EOF)) {
                                         ^
TFMpvalue.cpp:507:23: error: ‘optind’ was not declared in this scope
 OPTIONS[option] = optind-1;        
                   ^
make: *** [TFMpvalue-pv2sc] Error 1
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is something wrong with TFMpvalue.cpp:

1. `sudo chown username:username TFMpvalue.cpp`
2. Uncomment line 16 in TFMpvalue.cpp and change GetOpt.h into getopt.h